# Does Angular 2 support async injection?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-di

Let's say I have nested routes like so:

```
/products/:productId/parts/:partId
```

Two components are created `ProductComponent` and `PartComponent`.

In the product component I do `http.get('/api/products/' + productId)` that returns product object. I would be really nice if I could setup the injector so that PartComponent only resolved after product is available and have product passed into the constructor. Is it possible?

If not, what are my options of accessing retrieved product from `PartComponent` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a factory that returns a promise. In the constructor you get the product or null with `myFactory.then()`.
But the better way is to just inject a service and ask it for the product. I don't see a way to pass the product id to the injector.

Comment: If I ask the service to get me the product again. That means 2 requests will fire, one from each component. Then I need to get caching involved, correct?

Comment: Yes I think that is the simplest solution. Some caching probably won't hurt anyway. In the part component you might be able to inject the parent element and read it's "component" property but that introduces coupling and also must return a promise because it might not yet be set when you access it from part.